# How are similar bits separated?

Tags: arithmetic, signal-processing

A 1 is an "on" signal, and a 0 is an "off" signal. How does a computer know 01110 is different from 010? Does the computer wait between signals?

Comment: This is more of a question in electrical engineering.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The system operates in a synchronized fashion using a shared clock. This removes the ambiguity.